# Sending SMIME Encypted Mail( BouncyCastle) fails with java.io.IOException: ...has to be an instance of iaik.security.smime.EncryptedContent

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle, smime

I am stuck sending an S/MIME encrypted mail.

The Exception is always:
*javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
nested exception is:
java.io.IOException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Cannot write this object. It has to be an instance of iaik.security.smime.EncryptedContent or iaik.security.smime.SignedContent!*

I am using Bouncy Castle as Security Provider (according to my testoutput it states v1.69) although I am using the latest release 1.71 ...jdk18on-171...

I even broke it all down again just to match the provided example: *org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.examples.CreateEncryptedMail*

In addition to the provided code from the example I

- obtain my cerificate from a file
- I am setting the Mailcap in advance:

```
private void setDefaultMailcap() {
    final MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_signature");
    mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime");
    mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature");
    mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_mime");
    mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcap);
}
```

- configure SMTP server details:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new Authenticator() {
         protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
         }
      });
```

- and using...

`final Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");`
`transport.send(body);`

...to actually really send the mail

I am using the following libs:

- activation.jar
- bcmail-jdk18on-171.jar
- bcpkix-jdk18on-171.jar
- bcprov-ext-jdk18on-171.jar
- bcprov-jdk18on-171.jar
- bcutil-jdk18on-171.jar
- commons-codec-1.15.jar
- commons-io-2.11.0.jar
- junit.jar
- mail.jar

This produces the following Exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
java.io.IOException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Cannot write this object. It has to be an instance of iaik.security.smime.EncryptedContent or iaik.security.smime.SignedContent!
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1350)
javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:231)
javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
```

in my class

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Thomas